# Is the insert into ... where not exists costlier in performance?

Tags: oracle, performance, sql-insert, crud

We are using Oracle database (12c)

A table *ABCD* has below structure with around o(10^5) rows

CCOL* - Varchar2 column

DCOL* - Timestamp column

```
Name   Null?    Type              
----- -------- ----------------- 
CCOL1 NOT NULL VARCHAR2(64 CHAR) 
CCOL2 NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30 CHAR) 
CCOL3 NOT NULL VARCHAR2(64 CHAR) 
DCOL1 NOT NULL TIMESTAMP(6)      
CCOL4 NOT NULL VARCHAR2(64 CHAR) 
DCOL2 NOT NULL TIMESTAMP(6)      
CCOL5          VARCHAR2(32 CHAR)
```

The primary key on this table is (CCOL1, CCOL2)

We have a below insert statement:
Insert 1:

```
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO abcd (
        ccol1, ccol2, ccol3, dcol1, ccol4, dcol2, ccol5)
        SELECT
            :b1, :b2, :b3, :b4, :b5, :b6, :b7
        FROM
            dual
        WHERE
            NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT 1 FROM abcd  WHERE ccol1 = :b1 AND ccol2 = :b2 );
EXCEPTION
    WHEN dup_val_on_index THEN
        NULL;
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        RAISE;
END;
```

And alternative to this we have (removed the where not exists part)

Insert 2:

```
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO abcd (
        ccol1, ccol2, ccol3, dcol1, ccol4, dcol2, ccol5)
        VALUES 
        (:b1, :b2, :b3, :b4, :b5, :b6, :b7);

EXCEPTION
    WHEN dup_val_on_index THEN
        NULL;
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        RAISE;
END;
```

Which of these inserts is better?

Comment: For a single insert I doubt whether any difference would be worth the trouble of discovering its existence.

Comment: Another alternative would be to use a MERGE statement with just the `when not matched` clause.

Comment: if this is something which would be run multiple times, Insert 2 (with No Exists) would be a better option. irrespective of the usage of exists clause in the insert statement, ORACLE would still read the existing PK column values to make sure there is no conflict. So adding the external EXISTS could be overhead in this case.

Comment: though this is single insert, it's sandwiched with multiple other CRUD operations, and sometimes causes session blocking because of concurrency issues.

Comment: If you're worried about blocking, that's almost certainly a different issue where it's not going to matter which approach you use.  If this piece of code is causing blocking, that almost certainly means that two sessions are trying to insert the same primary key value and the second has to wait on the first to finish the rest of its transaction before it can return.  That isn't going to depend on the speed of this block of code, that's going to depend on how long the rest of the other session's transaction takes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're asking because you call this piece of code a large number of times.  Generally, which approach is faster will depend on how probable it is that the values you're inserting already exist in the table.  Throwing and catching an exception is orders of magnitude slower than checking that a primary key value does not already exist.  But if you're only going to throw the exception once on every million inserts, the second approach is likely to be more efficient.  When I had something like this in the past, there were also significant differences between Oracle versions in terms of how much more costly it was to throw and catch exceptions so the exact break-even point will vary depending on the Oracle version as well.  Realistically, you'd need to benchmark on your system to be sure.

Personally, I'd probably write this (as @Boneist suggest) as a `MERGE` with just a `when not matched` clause

```
MERGE INTO abcd dest
  USING( SELECT :b1 ccol1, :b2 ccol2, :b3 ccol3, ...
           FROM dual ) src
     ON( src.ccol1 = dest.ccol1 AND
         src.ccol2 = dest.ccol2 )
 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT( ccol1, ccol2, ccol3, ... )
      VALUES( src.ccol1, src.ccol2, src.ccol3, ... )
```

Separately, having a `WHEN OTHERS` exception handler that just does a `RAISE` doesn't make much sense-- just don't catch the exception if you aren't going to do anything with it.  In your first piece of code, it doesn't make sense to catch and ignore the `dup_val_on_index` check because you've already got the `NOT EXISTS` clause.  At that point, the `dup_val_on_index` is no longer an expected exception so you shouldn't be catching and ignoring it.